# How to skip outdated responses with angular?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, angular-http-interceptors

What is a best pattern to cancel outdated requests to server in angular (not angularjs)?

1. User initiate search request #1
2. User initiate search request #2
3. Server returns search response #2
4. Server returns Search response #1

As result, we are getting bug that request and response in UI do not match.

Typeahead, for instance, has typeahead-wait-ms attribute which partially helps, but I am looking for a more generic solution.

Is there easy pattern to cancel requests? Or compare request id with latest one?

PS: We are using HttpClient so our calls internally looks similar to following implementation for GET:

```
protected get<T>(url: string, request: any = {}, options: any = {}): Observable<T> {
    request.rnd = (new Date()).getTime();

    return this.http.get<T>(url, {headers: this.buildHeaders(options),
        responseType: 'json', params: request})
    .pipe(
            catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                ... error Handlig
            })
        );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

generally it looks like this, if you're using reactive forms, and your source for the string is a formcontrol:

```
searchSource = new FormControl('')
search(searchString: string) {
  // returns observable of search logic
}
ngOnInit() {
  this.searchSource.valueChanges.pipe(
    switchMap(toSearch => this.search(toSearch)) // switchmap automatically cancels old requests on new values
  ).subscribe(results => {
    // always results for LAST emitted value
  })  
}
```

the key is using `switchMap` at the source of your value of interest so that you are only looking at the result of the latest value.

Comment: Thanks, looks very relevant. Will accept upon confirmation

Comment: this will be it generally, you just need to get your value that you want to switch off into your stream. reactive forms are nice as they put form values in a stream for you already (and you can use any relevant operators like `debounce` as needed), but if you can't, like if a button click is the trigger, you can just create your own subject and trigger it on user click.